# Java Swing Application - Setter Not Working

Tags: java, swing, getter-setter

I am writing a java application that makes use of swing. The two main methods i am using are called Main and logInScreen. I have a variable in login screen that is initially set to "Empty", but will then be set to "Y" if a button is pressed using a setter(inside of an action listener). The problem i'm having is that i can't access this value in the main method by using a getter. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is the relevent code from main:

```
while (cont == true) {

                answer = login.getEntered();

                if (answer.equals("Y")) {

                    cont = false;

                } else {

                    cont = true;

                }
            }
```

Here is the code for the GUI:

```
package com.company;

/*



 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class logInScreen extends JFrame {

    private static String usernameInput = "";
    private static String passwordInput = "";

    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private static String entered = "";

    public logInScreen() {


        setEntered("empty");

        this.setTitle("Log In");
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        usernameArea();
        passwordArea();
        button("Log In");
        createNewAccount();
        this.add(panel);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void usernameArea() {

        JTextArea username = new JTextArea(1, 15);
        username.setText("");
        username.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(username, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        panel.add(pane);

    }

    public static void passwordArea() {
        JTextArea password = new JTextArea(1, 15);
        password.setText("");
        password.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane pane2 = new JScrollPane(password, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        panel.add(pane2);


    }


    public void button(String text) {

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText(text);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setEntered("Y");
                System.out.println(getEntered());

            }
        });

        panel.add(btn);

    }

    public static void createNewAccount(){

        JTextArea label = new JTextArea(1,30);
        label.setLineWrap(true);
        label.setEditable(false);
        label.setText("                                             New User?");

        panel.add(label);

        JButton newAccount = new JButton();
        newAccount.setText("Create New Account!");

        newAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                createLoginScreen newAccount = new createLoginScreen();

            }
        });

        panel.add(newAccount);

    }

    public void setEntered(String val){

        entered = val;

    }

    public String getEntered() {

        return entered;

    }

    public String getUsernameInput() {

        return usernameInput;

    }

    public String getPasswordInput() {

        return passwordInput;

    }

    public void close() {

        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove static keyword from `entered` variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i still can't get it to work, even without the static keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`while (cont == true) {` is likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread preventing pretty much anything from running.  Even if it isn't, it's a bad idea.

Use a modal dialog instead, which will block at the point when the dialog is made visible and continue running when it's closed, at which point you can determine the values which have been entered.

See [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693776/java-gui-multiple-frames/13694083#13694083) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299864/login-system-i-dont-know-hot-to-do-it/34300658#34300658)

Also, remove all the `static` declarations, this is not going to help you and will cause no end of issues as the solution becomes more complex